# Forwarding packets from NIC to WiFi using raw sockets in kernel space

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming, raw-sockets

For a project, I have 2 laptops with 2 wireless interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) and one NIC, let's call the laptops Sender and Receiver. What I would like to do is to send the odd packets that arrive to Sender through its Ethernet interface through wlan0 and even packets through wlan1 to the Receiver laptop. I want to do so by any means that allow me to inspect every packet by code so that I can modify anything if needed or change the sending policy and I want to do it in kernel space because for this particular task low latency is very important.

Assuming all interfaces are correctly set up (wlan0 from Sender connected to wlan0 from Receiver and the same for wlan1) would Raw Sockets be the fastest choice?

Is there any "easy" way to change 802.3 headers to 802.11 headers?

The steps I am going to try are roughly:

1. Open a Receiving Raw Socket and a Sending Raw Socket
2. Receive the Ethernet packet, and extract the upper layers
3. Encapsulate it with 802.11 headers
4. Send the modified packet over the Raw Socket

The only step I am not clear on is the 3rd one, I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a simple userspace raw socket, there is literally no reason to do this in kernel space, the network latency even on a local network is orders of magnitudes higher than the latency between user and kernel space. Also, networking in kernel space is a lot more complicated.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli for more complex server management, for example, handle multiple connections and sending multiple things at once from a user, we need better process management. any struct or libraries or other things that I can start work with the wireless card? the source code for ethernet is available. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there any "easy" way to change 802.3 headers to 802.11 headers?

Yes. And this is the only right way to deal with them. Do not change them!  Both 802.3 and 802.11 are part of the Data Link layer of the OSI model. Processing these headers is the business of the NIC driver but not your business, at least until you are interested in programming a specific NIC device. According to your project description, you need to capture every frame pushed out from the RX queue of the NIC driver of the Ethernet card and forward them to the TX queue of either driver of one WLAN NIC or another WLAN NIC. You need just a policy that will replace the MAC address of the recipient appropriately in the middle -- bridging.

2. Would Raw Sockets be the fastest choice?

Sockets is a userspace process-oriented interface to networking facilities implemented in the kernel. You mentioned that you care about latency and thus plan to implement bridging in the kernel -- therefore, below the sockets interface. In the kernel mode, you have to deal with socket buffer descriptors (`struct sk_buff`) that encapsulate frames with respective metadata and rely on the so-called New API (NAPI). You can look at `struct net_device` and field `rx_handler`,  which seems to be implemented primarily for bridging purposes.